# @EnableMethodSecurity caused @Value evaluation failure in @WebMvcTest using SprigBoot 3

Tags: java

We are using Spring Security (with **@EnableMethodSecurity**) for **@PreAuthorize()** in our microservice in SpringBoot 3 and JVM 17. We also have unit tests to cover the controllers using **@WebMvctest**.

When running the test code, it complains the **@Value** cannot be evaluated:

*Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean'; Invalid boolean value [${myFeature.active:true}]*

However, if I remove @EnableMethodSecurity in the config file, the test code runs fine.

Here is the config

```
@Configuration(enforceUniqueMethods = false)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class config {

}
```

Here is the unit test:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = DocApiController.class)
class DocApiControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    private DocService service;

    @Test
    void test_getDocuments_success() throws Exception {
        Result response = new Result();
        when(service.search(any())).thenReturn(response);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/document/get?pageSize=10&pageNumber=1"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```